# Add a timer to my code

Tags: java, android, timer, draw

I want to add a timer that, on every tick of the timer (1second), causes the line to refresh. How do I use the timer in my code?

The following is my code:

**LineRefresh.java**:

```
package LineRefresh.xyz.com;

import java.util.Timer;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class LineRefresh extends Activity {
DrawView drawView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    drawView = new DrawView(this);
    drawView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    setContentView(drawView);
}
```

}

**DrawView.java**:

```
package LineRefresh.xyz.com;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.view.View;

public class DrawView extends View {
Paint paint = new Paint();

public DrawView(Context context) {
    super(context);

}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
 paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    canvas.drawLine(50, 200, 270, 200, paint);
}

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here the sollution with Java's Timertask:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                hereYourMethod();
                }
            }
        };
        timer.schedule(task, 1000,1000);// (the task, when to start, when to repeat)
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way you can do this is the following:

```
Handler updateHandler;

@Override
public void onCreateBundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  updateHandler = new Handler();
  // Do this first after 1 second
  updateHandler.postDelayed(RecurringTask, 1000);
}

Runnable RecurringTask = new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    // Do whatever you want

    // Call this method again every 30 seconds
    updateHandler.postDelayed(this, 30000);
  }
};
```

I had some trouble marshaling to the UI thread with the Timer/TimerTask solution, so here is another one that ended up working for me!

Comment: +1 Does the trick for me as a Android newbie with rusty Java!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative would be using a Handler.

```
mHandler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback()
{
    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(Message msg)
    {
        if(msg.what == REFRESH)
        {
            // TODO Refresh Code

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
});

mHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(REFRESH, mMilliSecondsToRefresh);
```

Then when you want it to stop (this should also go in onStop() so that it doesn't continue in the background when your app isnt active):

```
mHandler.removeMessages(REFRESH);
```

Comment: Typically the handler creation would be in onCreate(). The mHandler variable itself would be defined in the class as a member. The sendEmptyMessageDelayed() method would go in onCreate() or on a button to click to start the refresh sequence off.

Comment: I am not sure the best action for Line refreshing. I haven't fiddled with that in Android. I have however given you a good method for automating the refreshing. Looking at the code though, I'm not sure why it would need refreshing. The onDraw() is overridden, which to me should mean that it should perform the code inside it whenever it is drawn (every frame?). If it isn't something that is performed automatically then perhaps you can find a way to reach the onDraw() method from inside the Handler to refresh it that way.

Comment: @Knossos This will only update once (after mMilliSecondsToRefresh) and then stop. It will not in fact continue to run.

Answer (score -1):

You can let the thread to sleep for 1 second:

```
Thread.sleep(1000); //1000 milliseconds = 1 second
```

If you're using Swing, best to use **Swing timer**: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html

In your case, maybe you should use **Timer**: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html

Comment: Keep in mind that we're in Android here, so Swing is not available. Also, you'd have to use a handler anyway, since you can perform UI changes only within the UI thread. And you definately shouldn't put the UI thread to sleep.