# timertask doesn't work!

Tags: java, android, timer, draw

i have tried using a timertask to refresh a line(after every 1 second) drawn with fixed point coordinates. But the line doesn't appear to refresh...is there anything wrong in my code?

LineRefresh.java:

```
package LineRefresh.xyz.com;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class LineRefresh extends Activity {
DrawView drawView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    drawView = new DrawView(this);
    drawView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    setContentView(drawView);

}
}
```

DrawView.java:

```
package LineRefresh.xyz.com;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.view.View;

public class DrawView extends View {
Paint paint = new Paint();

public DrawView(Context context) {
    super(context);    
}

@Override
public void onDraw(final Canvas canvas) { 
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    canvas.drawLine(50, 200, 270, 200, paint);  

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            canvas.drawLine(50, 200, 270, 200, paint);
            }
    };
    timer.schedule(task, 1000,1000);
}

}
```

sholud i,instead, place the timertask somewhere else in my code?

Comment: Having a thread run in onDraw is probably one of the worst design approaches I've ever seen in any language in any project.

Answer (score 1):

Rather use **Android Handler** to update  UI after certain time.

Comment: I suggested that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4277032/i-want-to-add-a-timer-to-my-code But for some reason he is intent on churning out questions about the same thing.